# How do I update Lucid kernel

Tags: 10.04, kernel, updates

Recently I have installed Lucid in my PC, I have a low internet connection speed, but I want to update my kernel.

So, I go to update manager to update it. But, I'm confused what is the package to update the kernel. **I just need to update my kernel** not another application.

So, what should I do? (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of *Ubuntu* is in the package `linux-image-$version`, to see what packages of this type you have installed, do in a terminal the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

The update of kernel package, like of any other packages, will be automatically proposed by the system, if available.

If you suspect the update manager is not working properly, execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and post any errors they show.

If you otherwise need to upgrade to a newer kernel not available in lucid repos, you can download and install that of your choice on

> http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

but be aware that they are not specifically tested against your system.